# Arduino Loop Confusion

Tags: c++, arduino

I'm creating an auto watering system for some plants. I am using a motor to control them, and soil sensors to tell when they need water. But I'm having trouble both understanding how I should be approaching this and secondly why my code isn't working. My problem is that the while loop is never initialized, and so the motor never stops I can tell this by my serial monitor.

```
      if(sensorVal1 <= thresholdDown1){
Serial.println("Plant Group 1 is Dry!");
Serial.println(sensorVal1);
Serial.println("Watering");
digitalWrite(in1, LOW); //LEFT
digitalWrite(in2, HIGH);
analogWrite(enA, 255);

delay(6250);


startTime = millis();
while(sensorVal1 <= thresholdDown1){
  Serial.println("Stopping");
    digitalWrite(in1, LOW);
digitalWrite(in2, LOW);

      if(sensorVal1 >= thresholdUp1){
     break;
   }
}



      totalTime = millis() - startTime;
      digitalWrite(in1, HIGH); //RIGHT
      digitalWrite(in2, LOW);
      delay(500);
      digitalWrite(in1, LOW); //OFF
      digitalWrite(in2, LOW);
      delay(totalTime);
      digitalWrite(in1, HIGH);
      digitalWrite(in2, LOW);
      delay(500);
      digitalWrite(in1, LOW);
      digitalWrite(in2, LOW);
      delay(totalTime);    
      digitalWrite(in1, HIGH);
      digitalWrite(in2, LOW);
      delay(3000);
      digitalWrite(in1, LOW);
      digitalWrite(in2, LOW);


      }
```

Comment: I assume you mean the `while` loop you show? In which you have `sensorVal1` and `threshholdDown1` as variables in the condition? But you never modify *any* of those variables inside the loop? That means the values of the variables will stay the same, forever, as long as you're looping.

Comment: What do you mean by that?, the values are measured in my void loop() as so:   int sensorVal1 = analogRead(sensor1);. Is there something i'm missing with what you're trying to say? I don't see this as a for loop, as the water in the pot changes the outside variable. Do I need to read the sensor inside the while loop?, but again it still doesn't explain why the loop is being skipped.

Comment: Do you modify either `sensorVal1 ` or `thresholdDown1` inside your `while` loop? If not then you have a loop condition that will never change, and you have a possible infinite loop.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude But, it still never goes into it? I'll try that but it doesn't get stuck or anything it just doesn't enter it.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Just tried, still confirms my problem. Nothing happens, did not print anything.

Comment: How do you initialize the sensor value in the first place, before the loop?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a *very* simple logic you can try :

```
if( sensorVal <= treshold ) {
  Serial.println("Watering");
  waterOn();
} else {
  Serial.println("NOT watering");
  waterOff();
}
```